# Listening around Handlebars render

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

What I'd like to achieve is:

- after a template is rendered bind to form submit to add a spinner
- before a template is rendered remove the spinner if present

I guess it'd be easy to achieve if there were a way to bind around Handlebars' rendering. I haven't yet found any clues that it would be possible.

The way I'm trying to solve this might not be the correct way, so feel free to suggest other means.

It's a single-page-app using [Davis](http://davisjs.com/) for routing and jQuery for DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem of binding to form submit could be solved with jQuery's [on handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) { ... });`. That works for all the forms whenever they're appended to the DOM.

For the rendering part, make a small jQuery plugin that wraps the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) call and [triggers](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) an event. Then bind the content element to listen for that. E.g. `$("#content").bind("render", function() { /* REMOVE SPINNER */ });` and `$("#content").render(/* WHATEVER IT TAKES TO GET HTML OUT OF HANDLEBARS */);`. And finally the plugin:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.render = function(htmlString) {
    var selector = this;
    selector.html(htmlString);
    selector.trigger("render");
  };
})(jQuery);
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hleinone/fkUfG/) to demonstrate the latter case (without Handlebars).